# Merging XPS files leaves open file handles to document references

Tags: c#, merge, xps, xpsdocument

I am merging XPS files via an IIS web application but during the merging process, it leaves the document reference file handles open. In a Windows WPF or console application, I wouldn't worry about the handles as they would get released after the application closed. Recycling the app pool would effectively close the handles too. However, I can't recycle the app pool just for closing the file handles due to caching and performance.

Is there a way to close these file handles after the merge is complete? I've tried a few different merging approaches, but the following code has given me the best results:

```
private DocumentPaginator CreateMergedDocument(IEnumerable<string> xpsFiles) {   
  using ( MemoryStream mergedStream = new MemoryStream() ) {
    using ( var pkg = Package.Open( mergedStream, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite ) ) {
      var pack = "pack://merged.xps";
      var uri = new Uri( pack, UriKind.Absolute );
      PackageStore.AddPackage( uri, pkg );
      using ( XpsDocument mergedDocument = 
          new XpsDocument( pkg, CompressionOption.Maximum, pack ) ) {
        FixedDocumentSequence seqNew = new FixedDocumentSequence();

        foreach ( string sourceDocument in xpsFiles ) {
          using ( XpsDocument xpsOld = 
              new XpsDocument( sourceDocument, FileAccess.Read ) ) {
            FixedDocumentSequence seqOld = xpsOld.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

            foreach ( DocumentReference dr in seqOld.References ) {
              DocumentReference newDocumentReference = new DocumentReference();
              newDocumentReference.Source = dr.Source;
              ( newDocumentReference as IUriContext ).BaseUri = 
              ( dr as IUriContext ).BaseUri;
              seqNew.References.Add( newDocumentReference );
            }
          }
        }

        XpsDocumentWriter xpsWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter( mergedDocument );
        xpsWriter.Write( seqNew );

        PackageStore.RemovePackage( uri );

        return seqNew.DocumentPaginator;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tracked down the file handles opening to the `xpsWriter.Write(seqNew)` line of code. This is expected as it needs to load the files to copy into the new `FixedDocumentSequence`. However, it would be nice if an `XpsDocumentWriter` was disposable and cleaned up its unmanaged resources/file handles.

During my research, I have tried a few other approaches. One approach I've tried is writing each page visual to a `SerializerWriterCollator`. Another approach I've looked into is processing the FixedPage contents and updating the URIs to copied image and font streams and writing back the raw XAML to the `XmlWriter`. Neither have worked too well. With the page visuals and `SerializerWriterCollator`, I was getting incorrect page sizes on the merged XPS and it was cutting off content. With the raw `XmlWriter` approach, it was jumbling some of the images in the merged XPS and incorrectly displaying some of the page content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I found that the original code used for running my function in an STA thread was not properly releasing file handles and unmanaged resources. We had a custom threading class with a custom implementation of invoking an action and running join on the thread. The thread was not exiting correctly after the action method completed. To fix this, I wrapped my code in a block similar to this:

```
private static readonly TaskScheduler _staScheduler = new StaTaskScheduler( 1 );

[Route( "merge" )]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MergeXps() {
  var paginator = await Task<DocumentPaginator>.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
      {
        var xpsFiles = Directory.GetFiles( "C:\\Xps", "*.xps" );
        var documentPaginator = CreateMergedDocument( xpsFiles );

        return documentPaginator;
      },
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None,
    _staScheduler );

  var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
  response.Content = new StringContent( $"Merged Document Page Count: {paginator.PageCount}" );
  response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
  return response;
}
```